# Cordova + Angular: Images not showing

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I have the following project structure:

```
MyProject
    - platforms
    - plugins
    - resources
    - www
        - css
        - img
        - js
        - views
        - index.html
```

My index.html is simple and straight:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myProject">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-view></div>

    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My app.js is the following:

```
var myProject = angular.module('myProject', ['ngRoute']);

myProject.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'RootController',
        templateUrl: 'views/RootControllerView.html'

    }).when('/theaters', {
        controller: 'TheatersController',
        templateUrl: 'views/TheatersControllerView.html'

    }).when('/settings', {
        controller: 'SettingsController',
        templateUrl: 'views/SettingsControllerView.html'

    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

///////// CONTROLERS ////////////////////////////

myProject.controller('RootController', function ($scope, recommendedMoviesFactory) {

    // Controller is going to set recommendedMovies
    // variable for the $scope object in order for view to
    // display its contents on the screen as html 
    $scope.recommendedMovies = [];

    // Just a housekeeping.
    // In the init method we are declaring all the
    // neccesarry settings and assignments
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.recommendedMovies = recommendedMoviesFactory.getRecommended();
    }
});

myProject.controller('TheatersController', function ($scope, theatersFactory) {

    // This controller is going to set theaters
    // variable for the $scope object in order for view to
    // display its contents on the screen as html 
    $scope.theaters = [];

    // Just a housekeeping.
    // In the init method we are declaring all the
    // neccesarry settings and assignments
    init();

    function init() {
        $scope.theaters = theatersFactory.getTheaters();
    }
});

myProject.controller('SettingsController', function ($scope) {

});

///////////// FACTORIES ////////////////////////////

myProject.factory('recommendedMoviesFactory', function () {
    var recommended = [
        {
            name: 'World War Z',
            description: 'The story revolves around United Nations employee Gerry Lane (Pitt), who traverses the world in a race against time to stop a pandemic',
            img: 'img/wardwarz.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Star Trek Into Darkness',
            description: 'When the crew of the Enterprise is called back home, they find an unstoppable force of terror from within their own organization has detonated the fleet and everything it stands for',
            img: 'img/intodarkness.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'The Iceman',
            description: 'Appearing to be living the American dream as a devoted husband and father in reality Kuklinski was a ruthless killer-for-hire.',
            img: 'img/iceman.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Iron Man 3',
            description: 'When Stark finds his personal world destroyed at his enemys hands, he embarks on a harrowing quest to find those responsible.',
            img: 'img/ironman.png'
        },
        {
            name: 'Django Unchained',
            description: 'Set in the South two years before the Civil War, Django Unchained stars Jamie Foxx as Django',
            img: 'img/django.png'
        }
    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getRecommended = function () {
        return recommended;
    }

    return factory;
});

myProject.factory('theatersFactory', function () {
    var theaters = [
        {
            name: 'Everyman Walton',
            address: '85-89 High Street London'
        },
        {
            name: 'Ambassador Cinemas',
            address: 'Peacocks Centre Woking'
        },
        {
            name: 'ODEON Kingston',
            address: 'larence Street Kingston Upon Thames'
        },
        {
            name: 'Curzon Richmond',
            address: '3 Water Lane Richmond'
        },
        {
            name: 'ODEON Studio Richmond',
            address: '6 Red Lion Street Richmond'
        }
    ];

    var factory = {};

    factory.getTheaters = function () {
        return theaters;
    }

    return factory;
});
```

And the RootControllerView:

```
<header>
    <h1>Pomidoro App</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <form>
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
    </form>
</nav>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">
                <img src="../img/ic_logout.png">
                <div>Movies</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/theaters">
                <img src="../img/ic_profile.png">
                <div>Theaters</div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#/settings">
                <img src="../img/ic_settings.png">
                <div>Settings</div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Recommended movies</li>
        <li data-ng-repeat="movie in recommendedMovies">
            <a href="#/theaters">
                <div><img src="../img/ic_settings.png">
                </div>
                <strong>{{movie.name}}</strong>
                <br />
                <p>{{movie.description}}</p>
                <span></span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see i am just presenting some informations about some videos. It is from the [this tutorial](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/how-to-build-angularjs-based-native-mobile-application/). However... when i now start the app on my android device... the images arent loaded. No img is appearing but the pathes are correct.

Why arent the images showing up?

**Edit 1**

I also tried it on server with

```
cordova serve android
```

there also the images arent loading.

Comment: try use `ng-src` & does images are loaded from different domain?

Comment: what? different domain? they are in my folder 'img' like i showed in post above. i test on android device. and where should i try ng-src. what is it and why?

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src

Comment: no, ng-src did not the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your paths used here are not correct.  The source for `img` tags is relative to your app, not relative to the location of the view. The example that you are following does not use `../`, and you should not be using it either.

Instead of using `<img src="../img/ic_logout.png">`, you should use `<img src="img/ic_logout.png">`.

Angular is injecting your view into the page, inside the `ng-view` element.  The view may be located in a `/views/` directory but the page itself is not.  The page is still at the root, and the browser is not aware of the `/views/` directory and cannot process the `../` in the `src` tag.  Angular **never** uses file locations relative to the view templates.

Comment: it would be true if these paths are used but they arent. i just use `<div><img src="../img/ic_settings.png">` in the repeat of the  RootControllerView

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? you have `../` littered everywhere in this view, but it doesn't make sense anywhere, repeater or no.

Comment: the pathes for the images defined in my app.js 'recommendedMoviesFactory' arent used. as i wrote i just use the images defined in the RootControllerView. And the relative pathes i used there should be correct. The RootControllerView is under www/views. so i have to go ../img/ to access the images.

Comment: no, really, please TRY it before you insist that it's wrong.  Angular **DOES NOT** use a path relative to where the view file is located.

Comment: have you looked in the console to see what the paths are for the 404 errors when the images are being loaded?