# Angular calls empty ng-repeat once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular website I've got a simple ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in prop.images">
    <img src="/doc/{{ image.id }}?width=200">
</div>
```

and when opening the website prop.images is empty in the controller:

```
$scope.prop = {};
$scope.prop.images = [];
```

but in my server log I see a call to

```
GET /doc/%7B%7B%20image.id%20%7D%7D?width=200
```

For the rest the ng-repeat is fine. If new images are loaded into `$scope.prop.images` they show up fine and everything works as expected.

Does anybody know why this initial call is made? All tips are welcome!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src/27554837#27554837

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ng-src` instead of `src` as attribute
Look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) for more

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ng-src` instead of `src` directly.

```
<img ng-src="/doc/{{ image.id }}?width=200">
```

The first initial call to the image with `src="/doc/{{ image.id }}?width=200"` is not Angular but your browser when parsing and rendering the DOM

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-src` instead of `src`. This will solve the issue.