# Rails, PaperClip, Rabl, AngularJS and path to image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

So I have Rails with Paperclip and Rabl on backend. On frontend I have Angular.
In rabl I append url of photo, what I want to display in frontend.

So on frontend i have this link
"/public/system/photos/photos/000/000/002/thumbnail/front.jpg"

When I try display image via src.

I get 404 error on response and No route matches [GET] "/public/system/photos/photos/000/000/002/thumbnail/front.jpg" in rails console.

I don't know what i did wrong.

How i can access to this static content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build your own endpoint to download the url...
In your controller, you need to do something like this:

```
def download
  instance = YourModel.find(params[:id])
  send_file(instance.file.path, type: instance.file_content_type, disposition: 'inline')
end
```

> `file` is your paperclip attribute

In your *routes.rb*

`get '/your_controller/:id/download', to: 'your_controller#download', as: :download`

So, in your browser you can paste the url: `http://localhost:3000/your_controller/xxx/download` to get the file.

In your rabl view...

```
node(:my_url) do |instance|
  download_url(instance.id)
end
```

> `download_url` will work if you have `as: :download` option in your routes only.

To show the image using angular use `ng-src` instead of `src`. Take a look to [Use of ng-src vs src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src)