# How reload image by src updating from $http request?

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<img src='img/product/{{ product.img }}.png' width='300' />
```

JS:

```
$http.post('services/service.php', {
     // some data
}).then(function(response) {
     $scope.product.img = response.data.imgTemp;
}, function(response) {             

});
```

With JQuery, I would try:

```
$('#imgID')[0].src = 'img/' + objResponse.fileNameTemp + '.png?' + new Date();
```

But in Angular, with `src` linked to `$scope.product.img` variable, I asume if I update this variable it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of ng-src vs src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `src` to `ng-src`:

```
<img ng-src='img/product/{{ product.img }}.png' width='300' />
```

Angular has [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) on this.

Comment: Not working. result is: <img ng-src="img/product/1405547457.png" width="300" class="productImage" src="img/product/1405547457.png"> but img not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution :) After `$scope.product.img = ...` need to apply scope update: `$scope.$apply();`