# 404 Image not found on ng-repeat in ionic / angular for first image only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

So I am using the following code to output a few images on my html page

```
<div ng-repeat="Object in Objects"><img src="{{Object.Image}}"></div>
```

This works great and loops out all my image objects and everything is great. However I set the $scope.Objects variable inside my controller. So when I first boot up my web page I get a 404 not found for

```
http://192.168.1.180:8100/%7B%7BObject.Image%7D%7D
```

Again, everything is working all my images are showing up, but I am getting several 404 errors ( I do this in a few places) and I am trying to get rid of them.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27554935/870729

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ng-src instead. Need that for images to use angular data.

If you don't, your initial src value isn't a valid url, so it causes your browser errors.

But, if you use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead, angular solves that problem on your behalf.

```
<img ng-src="{{Object.image}}" />
```

With that little gem, angular won't set the element's src property until it's ready with actual data.

Comment: Come on, give a fuller answer.  Show an example.

Comment: That is perfect! ahhh thank you. I will accept as soon as SO will let me.

Comment: Ok. Example in place. Somehow I feel like I should write more - but it's a nice simple fix :-)