# img src if else gives error but still works

Tags: html, image

I have the following code in HTML:

```
<img src="{{ value ? '../images/online_pic.png' :'../images/offline_pic.png'}}" 
alt="{{ value ? 'online' : 'offline' }}"
class="healthpic">
```

Which shows a different picture depending on a value in the controller. The problem here is that although the pictures are correctly loaded in the page I still get a **404 not found** in the console log. This gives me the felling that although everything works it can still crash any minute.

Does anyone know how to prevent this? Or is this just something i have nothing to worry about?

Comment: And are the images not found? Or any other file?

Comment: It's probably because javascript executes after a while and your image looks for an image named `{{ value ? '../images/online_pic.png' :'../images/offline_pic.png'}}`  
  
Look at this if you're using angular: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src

Comment: What is the request URL corresponding to the 404 error shown in the console log?