# How does angular still render a image if I use src instead of ng-src?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As per angular docs and their explanation we should use `ng-src` instead of `src` in an image tag where the image url is an angular expression.

e.g. `<img ng-src="{{country.flagURL}}" width="100">`

But in my case if I use `src`, the browser still renders the image. In the console I can see one failed call for the image where it's trying to access the exact expression like `.../Desktop/%7B%7Bcountry.flagURL%7D%7D`

However, later there is another call for the image which is initiated from angular.js which actually renders the image and displays it in the browser.

So my question is - what is the use of `ng-src` if the same can be achieved by using `src`? It appears that only one extra network call will be there.
And what exactly happens in angular to render the image when I don't use `ng-src`?

Below is my code snippet. You can run and see.

```html
<html ng-app="countryApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Angular.js Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
      countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
        data = [
        {
          "name": "China",
          "population": 1359821000,
          "flagURL": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Flag_of_the_People%27s_Republic_of_China.svg"
        },
        {
          "name": "India",
          "population": 1205625000,
          "flagURL": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/41/Flag_of_India.svg"
        },
        {
          "name": "United States of America",
          "population": 312247000,
          "flagURL": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg"
        }
      ];
          $scope.countries = data;
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Population</th>
        <th>Flag</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
        <td>{{country.name}}</td>
        <td>{{country.population}}</td>
        <td><img src="{{country.flagURL}}" width="100"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what would happen if your browser load the image before initializing angular app. Image tag will have wrong src url, raw angular expression.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27554837/5376197) is an explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of ng-src vs src](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src)

Comment: @MatejP. , @CeylanMumunKocabas The one you are referring says that why to use `ngSrc` instead of `src`. My query is totally oposite, how is it working with `src`!!   
Hope this clears my query.

Comment: @maximusツ Yes exactly. Img tag would have wrong src url, hence it should not display the image. But in my case it's displaying the image and replacing the `src` correctly though I didn't use `ng-src`.  
So, how did that happen?

Comment: @DebajitMajumder, this is because browser tries to refresh image every time it `src` changes.  Try doing that manually by firebug. This means first time when the image url is invalid , browser still display wrong image data which will be corrected right after angular replaces the expression by valid value.

Comment: @maximusツ , yes, as I can see in the DOM that the `src` has been changed. There is my doubt. As per angular documentation i should use `ng-src` so that angular expression gets compiled and the `src` in the img tag should contain the exact url.  

As per docs / my understanding if I don't use `ng-src` the angular expression i.e. `src="{{country.flagURL}}"` should not be replaced by actual url. So, how is this angular expression getting updated by actual image url?

Comment: `src="{{country.flagURL}}"` will execute but it will not stop browser to load image before executing expression, but ng-src will. This is because `ng-src` directive will add `src` attribute to image tag. So no `src` tag, no image load. Check out this `ng-src` implementation here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0272240400d7896224f34b9f10b492994e29c655/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L353

Comment: your comment explains how `ng-src` works i.e. it will add `src` attribute to image tag and after that image will be loaded. But I didn't understand your first line i.e. only "before executing expression" part.  

Who will execute this expression `{{country.flagURL}}` inside `src` attr? I believe the above expression will execute ( i.e. replacing the expression by actual url ) only when I write it inside `ng-src`. Unless the angular expression is executed, it can't download the image from server.

Comment: `{{country.flagURL}}` will be executed just like any other angular expression because it is a valid angular expression.  But this will happen after angular is initialized. Before that browser will think the expression as URL and will try to load it from the server. Hence the invalid load request as you seeing in the web console.

Comment: Okay, well explained. I was under impression that if I don't write `ng-src` then the image will not render only. So, `src` attribute will do my work, visually there won't be any impact, it's just one extra invalid(failed) call to server until angular evaluates the expression. @maximusツ you may convert this to an answer.

Comment: @DebajitMajumder _So, src attribute will do my work, visually there won't be any impact_ . `src` may not work on all browsers(eg. old IE browsers)

Comment: @AvantikaSaini Yes, may be it will not work in few older browsers. Anyway I just said that for the sake of understanding the concept. However I got that, it is always recommended to use `ng-src`, why to make an extra `GET` request when we know that the call is going to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
<img ng-src="{{country.flagURL}}" width="100">
```

Angular will not load the image until expression inside ng-src is evaluated.

But with,

```
<img src="{{country.flagURL}}" width="100">
```

browser tries to load the image with raw (non evaluated) expression which leads to failed `GET` request to server. But as soon as angular load and evaluates the expression under `src` tag, browser re-render the image tag with new url value.

So in nutshell, `ng-src` just stops loading of image until angular execute the expression to avoid initial invalid request (with invalid URL). Checkout the  implementation of `ng-src` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/0272240400d7896224f34b9f10b492994e29c655/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L353). It just adds `src` tag image which leads `GET` request for the image.