# ng-repeat in angular js directive produces 404 in browser console

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

i have a very simple angular js directive that loops over a collection using ng-repeat and simply generates an ordered list containing images. The directive works but I have noticed an extra console error in the browser (chrome).

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <custom-directive image-count="4"></custom-directive>
</div>

angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('customDirective', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:   '<ul>'+
                        '<li ng-repeat="i in collection">'+
                            '<img src="http://placehold.it/{{i}}00x100.jpg" />'+
                        '</li>'+
                    '</ul>',
        scope: {
            imageCount: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.collection = [];

            for(var i = 1; i < $scope.imageCount; i++){
                console.log(i);
                $scope.collection.push(i);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**codepen**
http://codepen.io/OmarCreativeDev/pen/OXjQJw?editors=1010

**console error** GET http://placehold.it/%7B%7Bi%7D%7D00x100.jpg 404 (Not Found)

**decoded console error** http://placehold.it/{{i}}00x100.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you tried using "ng-src" instead of src on the template ?

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).directive('customDirective', function() {
    'use strict';
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:   '<ul>'+
                        '<li ng-repeat="i in collection">'+
                            '<img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{i}}00x100.jpg" />'+
                        '</li>'+
                    '</ul>',
        scope: {
            imageCount: '@'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
            $scope.collection = [];

            for(var i = 1; i < $scope.imageCount; i++){
                console.log(i);
                $scope.collection.push(i);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: brilliant! ng-src as opposed to src has done the trick! cant believe I missed that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try ng-src in place of src

[Use of ng-src vs src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src)
[ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

```js
  '<img ng-src="http://placehold.it/{{i}}00x100.jpg" />'+
```