# Image is displayed but browser console shows a 404 error when setting image src using angularjs expression

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an `asp.net` mvc application on which I am also using `angularJS`.

I am having this strange problem were the correct image is displayed in the browser but the browser console shows a 404 error showing the raw `angularjs` code:

[image: Error in browser]

[image]

Here's the code in my view where I set the img's src:

```
    <a href="#" data-product-id={{item.Id}} class="link-product-name" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-product-details">
        <img data-product-id={{item.Id}} class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="{{rootUrl + item.imagePath}}" />
    </a>
```

`rootUrl` is a $scope variable.

I am new to both mvc and angularJS. I'd really appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks!

Comment: try using ´ng-src´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `src=`attribute by angular directive `ng-src=`

Using `ng-src` gives you expected result, because `rootUrl + item.imagePath` is evaluated and replaced by its value **after** angular is loaded.

```
<img data-product-id={{item.Id}} class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" ng-src="{{rootUrl + item.imagePath}}" />
```

But with `src`, the browser tries to load an image named {{`rootUrl + item.imagePath`}}, which results in a failed request.

For more info on `ng-src` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27554765/use-of-ng-src-vs-src)

Comment: That did it! Amazing! Thanks!